# Project Euler: problem 8

Tags: python

```
n = # some ridiculously large number, omitted
N = [int(i) for i in str(n)]
maxProduct = 0
for i in range(0,len(N)-4):
    newProduct = 1
    is_cons = 0
    for j in range(i,i+4):
        if N[j] == N[j+1] - 1:
        is_cons += 1
    if is_cons == 5:
        for j in range(i,i+5):
            newProduct *= N[j]
        if newProduct > maxProduct:
            maxProduct = newProduct
print maxProduct
```

I've been working on this problem for hours now and I can't get this to work. I've tried doing this algorithm on paper and it works just fine.. Could you give me hints what's wrong ?

Comment: Please include the code in your posting, not by linking Pastebin.

Comment: Post your code, what doesn't work?

Comment: @user: The question is what is wrong with the code the OP wrote. The solution was not requested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood the problem. Where it says "5 consecutive digits", that only means 5 digits that come one right after another - you're **not** supposed to check that the **values of the digits** are consecutive (i.e. each one greater than the last). So throw away all the `is_cons` logic and just check the product of each 5-digit chunk.

Comment: that makes sense! I had no clue where "is_cons" came from.

Answer (score 2):

Marijus, I'd recommend you to re-think the algorithm, that's a very weird way of solving the problem. It's much simpler, use the function `max`, a single iteration (a [generator expression](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/pytut/GeneratorExpressions.html), for example), and try to do it without temporal variables. It can be elegantly solved in just 2/3 lines (in fact, you could do it with a single line, but the abstraction of the [product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication#Capital_Pi_notation) function, for example, would be advisable, as you will use it in other Euler problems)

Answer (score 1):

One thing that looks wrong: `range(n, m)` gives you the numbers from n inclusive *to m exclusive*, i.e. `range(N, N+4)` gives you the *four* next indices (the problem wants *five* consecutive digits).

Comment: for j in range(i,i+4):
 if N[j] == N[j+1] - 1:
  is_cons += 1 What this does is check one digit ahead whether it is concusive to the current one and  that's why it has to stop at the 4th digit.. I think this is correct, isn't it ?

Comment: @Marijus: `range(i, i+)` is `[i, i+1, i+2, i+3]`. Don't you want `[i, i+1, i+2, i+3, i+4]`?

Answer (score 0):

I had worked out a solution that is inline with @tokland's post.

```
from itertools import islice
from operator import mul

def max_product(num, length=5):
    num_list = map(int, str(num))
    num_slices = (islice(num_list, x, x+length) for x in xrange(0, len(num_list)-length))
    return max(reduce(mul, y) for y in num_slices)
```

Itertool madness.

```
from itertools import izip, islice, imap, tee
from operator import mul

def max_product(num, length=5):
    num_lists = enumerate(tee(imap(int, str(num)), length))
    digit_slices = izip(*[islice(num_list, ord, None) for ord, num_list in num_lists])
    return max(reduce(mul, y) for y in digit_slices)
```

Comment: yup, that's more or less the idea I had in my mind (the first one, the second looks a bit overkill even for a itertool fanatic ;-))

Comment: @tokland, haha, I was thinking of writing one so that you had to pass in an iterable and that the only list created was for the number digits used in the multiplication.  Just as a proof of concept for creating very little memory overhead and supporting large iterable sequences of digits.  This however would take far more time than it deserved.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @tokeland, you probably need to rethink the algo. Also, as @delnan said, range(i,i+4) will give only 4 values. Here's a code that ought to do it

```
 n = str([whatever number])
 maximum = 0
 for i in range(0,len(n)):
     substr = n[i:i+5]
     product = 1
     for digit in substr:
         product *= int(digit)
         if product > maximum:
              maximum = product
 return maximum
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
number = '\
73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934\
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843\
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511\
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557\
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113\
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749\
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866\
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776\
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243\
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397\
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482\
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474\
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881\
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586\
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042\
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408\
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188\
84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606\
05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725\
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450'

print max([reduce(lambda accum, x : accum * x, [int(x) for x in number[i:i+5]]) for i in range(len(number) - 5)])
```

Comment: May I ask why we store this big number as `num = '\...'`? I mean, why do you put quotes and a slash around it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

10&#. 5 {.(}.~ I.@(= >./)@(5&(*/))) 10#.^:_1 number

is a J solution where number is the very long number as an extended integer.

It executes more or less from right to left, and parenthesis are used for two things - they pass along right arguments so that they can be used in more than one place, so that you don't have to create named intermediate variables, and to prioritize execution (of course, when an argument is passed in, it is clear that what is inside the parenthesis has to execute last, as opposed to first.  J is a very interesting language, parenthesis mean both execute first and execute later.  But in general, execution is right to left.  The number is cracked into digits, and the sum product of each overlapping group of five digits is taken. The greatest sum-product is found and compared back against that vector to create a boolean vector, where the index of the comparison is found.  The head of the original vector is then dropped, up to the index that was found.  Then a five digit hunk of that is extracted, and those five digits are glued back together.

I think that problems as low as 8 are really designed just go get you going in Euler - they are simple, most of them are one liners in J.

I am not sure whether I did this as a one liner first time around  I may have with an intermediate named variable - but since I have done a few of these problems, I believe I know J a lot better than I did, and I can put a phrase together like this without much problem, I know where to put the parenthesis.  In that, doing the euler exercises has been successful.